# Sharepoint Designer 2013 Logging Modified by In a List

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I currently have a workflow that sort of works.

I am trying to log a person into my list once they change a field:

Stage:Wait for Finance
    If Current Item:Is the Financial Section Complete? not equals Yes
        Wait for Is the Financial Section Complete? to equal Yes
Transition to stage
    Go to Set Financial

Stage:Set Financial
    If Current List:Is the Financial Section Complete? equals Yes
        Set Financial Manager to [%Current List:Modified By%]
    Log Financial section completed by: [%Cur... to the workflow history list
    Email Kimberly Abaid
Transition to stage
    Go to Wait for it

Stage:Wait for it
    If Current Item:Is the Systems Section Complete not equals Yes
        Wait for Is the Systems Section Complete to equal Yes
Transition to stage
    Go to Set Systems

Stage:Set Systems
    If Current Item:Is the Systems Section Complete equals Yes
        Set Systems Manager to [%Current List:Modified By%]
    Log Systems Section Completed by: [%Curre... to the workflow history list
    Email Kimberly Abaid
Transition to stage
    Go to End of Workflow

This sort of works except that when someone modifies their section (ie systems manager) it doesn't put their user name, it puts mine. How do I get the Modified by to put their name?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may have an action beforehand that updates the list item? If this is the case, save the Current Item Modified By to a variable before updating the list item, and make sure to set the Modified By in your update to that variable. This will prevent your update from interfering with your subsequent lookup, and you can just use the variable for logging :)